# How can I silence Rust warnings in macros from external crates?

Tags: macros, rust, warnings, static-analysis

Using `clap`'s `arg_enum` macro I get this warning:

```
warning: use of deprecated item 'std::ascii::AsciiExt': use inherent methods instead
  --> src/main.rs:37:1
   |
37 | / arg_enum!{
38 | |     #[derive(Debug)]
39 | |     pub enum Operation {
40 | |         Add,
...  |
47 | |     }
48 | | }
   | |_^
   |
   = note: #[warn(deprecated)] on by default
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)
```

How can I silence it? I've tried putting `#[allow(deprecated)]` before the `arg_enum!` and before the `extern crate clap;` but neither had any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible yet. [Add macro checks to lints (issue #48855)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/48855) is open to add such functionality.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this had [already](https://github.com/kbknapp/clap-rs/commit/b04a3b9ac97925a64c1dce6981359f7796cd9fc2#diff-e1576943a5907b15388ab726037ebdb3) been [fixed](https://github.com/kbknapp/clap-rs/issues/1274) and should not be an issue in the next release of `clap`. Until then you can silence the warning with `#![allow(deprecated)]`.

Comment: That disables all deprecated warnings in the file though right? So there's no way to control warnings for macros?

Comment: @Timmmm not outside of the macros' definitions, at least none that I know of.